# Convert array as string to array javascript

Tags: javascript

This might be a dumb question but I have a string like so:

```
"[1, 2, 3, 4]"
```

I want to convert it into an actual array:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

How do I go about this?

Comment: `JSON.parse("[1, 2, 3, 4]")` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just JSON parse it! `JSON.parse("[1, 2, 3, 4]")`

Answer (score 0):

```
var string = "[1, 2, 3, 4]";
JSON.parse(string);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use AND validate Tom Finney's or Ashishya11's or Hasee Amarathunga's answer because mine contains a gross security vulnerability if your string input comes from an untrusted source. But anyways, you can also do it like this:

```
const array = eval('[1, 2, 3, 4]')
```

Comment: or an alternative to eval, a function constructor: `const array = Function("return [1, 2, 3, 4]")()` - which apparently is supposed to be _less_ of a security threat, but can still be harmful

Comment: @nick no, it isn't. Also I don't get why this answer is necessary.

Comment: This answer is not *necessary*, I was just pointing out the fact that this is a solution to OP's question after 3 exact same solutions provided as answers. I can delete it if you find it harmful

Comment: @JonasWilms when you say “it isn’t” do you mean that it isn’t an alternative to eval or that it isn’t less of a security threat?

Comment: @nick both ... ...

Comment: @JonasWilms The reason that I thought it is is because of: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval under the “do not use eval” section it mentions that a better alternative is to use a function constructor

Comment: @JonasWilms so after reading that I don’t understand why “it isn’t”?

Comment: @nick well yes, the code executed via Function is not executed in the current scope ... but there are rarely cases where you'd use `eval` in an evil maner to extract variables. I guess it is mostly used for cross site scripting attacks, and then the attacker probably manipulates the DOM, which works with `eval` and `Function` (never seen those attacks in the wild though)

Comment: @JonasWilms I see, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
JSON.parse("[1, 2, 3, 4]")
```